# send the ID to the HTTP request

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-router

I have to send the ID of a client to the modify.html page from the clients.html page when I clic on the Modify link,this is what I have done:

clients.html:

```
<tbody>
        <tr  ng-repeat="post in posts>
            <td align="center">{{post.id}}</td>
            <td align="center">{{post.nom}}</td>
           <td align="center"><a ui-sref="app.modifier({customerID:post.id})">Modify</a></td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Modify.html:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Nom:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control rounded" ng-model="usernom">
               </div></div>
```

and the controller:

```
.controller('editController', ['$scope', '$http' ,function($scope,$http) { 
       $scope.errors = [];
      $scope.msgs = [];
      $scope.usershow = function() {
      $scope.errors.splice(0, $scope.errors.length); // remove all error messages
      $scope.msgs.splice(0, $scope.msgs.length);
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'MyURL?id='+$scope.userid+'&nom=test}).success(function(data, status, headers, config){ 
     if (data.msg != '')
                        {
                            $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $scope.errors.push(data.error);
                        }
                    }).error(function(data, status) { 
                        $scope.errors.push(status);
                    });}}])
```

and the config.router.js:

```
.state('app.modifier', {
           url: 'client/modifier/:customerID',
           templateUrl: 'tpl/modify.html',
           controller: 'editController'
              })
```

I can get the ID selected from the table in the URL of tha browser but I can't send it to the HTTP request
thanks for help
update:

this my essai:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'MyURL?id='+$stateParams.customerID +'&nom=test}).success(function(data, status, headers, config){ ....
```

but I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: $stateParams is not defined
```

Comment: Do you use want to do in context Single Page Application?

Comment: look into $stateParams to get the id from the url: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateparams-1

Comment: also, you should use the ``params`` object in your ``$http`` call: ``$http({method: 'GET', url: "MyURL", params: {id: myId, nom: 'test'}})``

Comment: @ khusnetdinov yes it's a single page application,ok  thanks @jlowcs I will try it,but how can the myId value change when I select the row from table :/ ??

Answer (score 1):

Just inject $stateParams in controller handling your Modify.html and set $stateParams.customerID to your $http request.

Comment: Your answer seems rather incomplete. Care to rephrase??

Comment: The second thing is that "app.modifier({customerID:post.id})" looks like you have some logic error. Your post.id never should be equal customerID. This can provide you many problems in future.